# How to define function with range [0,1] from values ranging [0,∞)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have two entities `A` and `B`; each is defined by two characters: `density (D)` and `grade (G)`.

Density has the range [0, ∞); grade has range [μ, ν]. The two entities are related together as follows.

If the density of B (Db) goes to 0, the grade of A (Da) goes to μ; viceversa: lim Db → ∞, Ga → ν.

I could define a function relating the two entities as follows:

```
    f(A|B) = μ + (ν-μ)ε(B)
```

where `ε` is a function that goes to 0 when lim Db → 1, and goes to 1 when lim Db → ∞.
The problem is that I don't know how to implement `ε`. I can't simply do ε=D, because G is a number well above 1. I could put ε=Db/Da, but Db might be larger than Da, thus ε>1. Neither I can do Db/max(Db) because max(Db) is ∞.

Is there some mathematical trick I could apply to define ε?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I have misunderstood your question, you need any function that has $f(1) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 1$. Many functions can do this, an example could be $f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x-1)$.

You can then make input the value of "Db" into this function and call the output "$\varepsilon$".